# Как убрать подсказки в DBeaver, которые появляются автоманически после написания названия таблицы? Пример: from Data_table dt

Tags: dbeaver

Как убрать подсказки в DBeaver, которые появляются автоманически после написания названия таблицы? Пример: from Data_table dt